# DRF Filter not working with Boolean Value with Postgres

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Getting the wrong output when using DRF Filter, It returns data based on user_id only looks like it hasn't consider itemmaster_item_active status for the query.

Views.py

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class ItemmasterAPIView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ItemmasterSerializer
    queryset = Itemmaster.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_class = ItemMasterItemFilter
```

Filters.py

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from itemmaster.models import Itemmaster, ItemmasterItem
class ItemMasterItemFilter(FilterSet):
    user_id = filters.CharFilter('itemmaster_updated_by_id')
    item_status = filters.BooleanFilter('itemmaster__itemmaster_item_active')

    class Meta:
        model = Itemmaster
        fields = ('user_id', 'item_status',)
```

Serializers.py

```
class ItemmasterItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    item_ref_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ItemmasterItem
        fields = ('item',  'itemmaster_item_active')
        
class ItemmasterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    itemmaster = ItemmasterItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Itemmaster
        fields = ( 'itemmaster', 'itemmaster_updated_by')
```

models.py

```
    itemmaster_updated_by = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='itemmaster_updated_by')
class ItemmasterItem(models.Model):
    itemmaster = models.ForeignKey(Itemmaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='itemmaster')
    itemmaster_item_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```